# Why google maps on my WebBrowser keep loading ? (Delphi XE6 and Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm using simple code to show google maps on the phone.
Add TLocationSensor, set property Active to True.

Add LocationChanged event handler :

```
procedure TLocationForm.LocationSensor1LocationChanged(Sender: TObject;
  const OldLocation, NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(
    Format(
      'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s',
      [NewLocation.Latitude.ToString, NewLocation.Longitude.ToString]
    )
  );
end;
```

Why my browser keep loading all the time ?

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: Because your location changes constantly.

Comment: When this event is triggered, save your location and compare it with the previous saved value. Load the page only if these values change in a meaningful way.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: Or using timer maybe? Update every 1 minute for example. If compare it with the previous value, so I should determine the inside range and outside range of previous value?

Answer (score 1):

You load the entire page when the location chamges.
Instead, you should load the page once, and center the map via javascript after that.
It should be something like map.setCenter() where you pass your current lat/lon.

Comment: Interesting! That's why maybe everytime I drag the map, it's disappeared (webbrowser become blanks) and start loading the map again. This behavior not happend in google maps application.